# How to start and stop GIF animated GtkImage in GTK+

Tags: c, gtk, gif, animated-gif

I have a `GTK+` application written in `C` that loads a matrix of animated `GIF` files. These `GtkImages` automatically run the animation when they are loaded and then stop when the animation is completed. How would I restart the animation of each `GtkImage` containing the `GIF` and are signals generated when the animation is complete?

Thank you.

**EDIT :

Would the use of `gdk_pixbuf_animation_get_iter()` described [here](http://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/2.22/gdk-pixbuf-animation.html#gdk-pixbuf-animation.description) make this possible?**

Full code is provided below.

```
/*
 * Compile me with:
 *   gcc -o reels reels.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk+-2.0 gmodule-2.0)
 */

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <time.h>

/* GTK */
#include <gdk/gdkx.h>
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

/**** prototypes ****/

static void destroy (GtkWidget*, gpointer);
GdkPixbuf *create_pixbuf(const gchar * filename);
GtkWidget *SetupWindow(gchar *data, const gchar *filename);
static void destroy (GtkWidget *window, gpointer data);
void btnSpin_clicked(GtkWidget *button, gpointer data);
void btnExit_clicked(GtkWidget *button, gpointer data);

/********************/

GtkWidget   *images[3][5];

static void destroy (GtkWidget *window, gpointer data)
{
  gtk_main_quit ();
}

void btnSpin_clicked(GtkWidget *button, gpointer data)
{
    printf("Spin Button pressed.\n");

    return;
}

void btnExit_clicked(GtkWidget *button, gpointer data)
{
    gtk_main_quit();

    return;
}


GtkWidget *SetupWindow(gchar *data, const gchar *filename)
{
    GdkPixmap *background;
    GdkPixbuf *pixbuf;
    GdkScreen *ourscreen;
    GdkColormap *colormap;
    GtkStyle *style;
    GdkColor fg;
    GdkColor bg;
    GError *error = NULL;
    GdkRectangle *rect;
    GtkWidget *window;

    pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_file (filename,&error);
    if (error != NULL) {
        if (error->domain == GDK_PIXBUF_ERROR) {
            g_print ("Pixbuf Related Error:\n");
        }
        if (error->domain == G_FILE_ERROR) {
            g_print ("File Error: Check file permissions and state:\n");
        }

        g_printerr ("%s\n", error[0].message);
    }

    gdk_pixbuf_render_pixmap_and_mask (pixbuf, &background, NULL, 0);
    style = gtk_style_new ();
    style->bg_pixmap[0] = background;
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), data);
    // gtk_window_maximize(GTK_WINDOW(window));
    gtk_window_set_modal (GTK_WINDOW (window),TRUE);
    gtk_window_set_default_size(GTK_WINDOW(window),628,530);
    gtk_widget_set_style (GTK_WIDGET(window), GTK_STYLE(style));
    gtk_window_set_position(GTK_WINDOW(window),GTK_WIN_POS_CENTER_ALWAYS);
    gtk_container_set_border_width(GTK_CONTAINER(window), 0);
    //gtk_window_set_resizable(GTK_WINDOW(window), (gboolean) FALSE);
    gtk_window_set_decorated( GTK_WINDOW(window), FALSE );    

    return(window);
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GdkPixbufAnimation *animation;
    GtkWidget *image;
    int x,y;    
    GdkPixbuf *pixBuf;
    GdkPixmap *pixMap;
    gchar filename[20];
    GtkWidget *btnSpin, *btnExit;

    GtkWidget *frame;       /* for absolute positionining of widgets */
    GtkWidget *window;
    int posx, posy;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);

    window = SetupWindow("Demo", "background.gif");
    g_signal_connect (G_OBJECT (window), "destroy", G_CALLBACK (destroy), NULL);

    frame = gtk_fixed_new();
    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), frame);

    btnSpin = gtk_button_new_with_label("Spin");
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(btnSpin, 80, 35);
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame), btnSpin, 229, 485);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT( btnSpin ), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(btnSpin_clicked), NULL );

    btnExit = gtk_button_new_with_label("Exit");
    gtk_widget_set_size_request(btnExit, 80, 35);
    gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame), btnExit, 320, 485);
    g_signal_connect(G_OBJECT( btnExit ), "clicked", G_CALLBACK(btnExit_clicked), NULL );

    /* setup animated gifs */
    for( y = 0; y < 3; y++ )
    {
        posy = (y*120) + 20;
        for( x = 0; x < 5; x++ )
        {
            posx = (x*120) + 20;
            /* set each Image widget to spin GIF */
            sprintf( filename,"%d-%d.gif", y+1,x+1 );
            images[y][x] = gtk_image_new_from_file(filename);
            gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame), images[y][x], posx, posy);
        }
    }

    gtk_widget_show_all(window);

    gtk_main ();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure you can actually do that...

Comment: Thank you ptomato. I sure hope this is possible.

Comment: It's hard to tell what animation iters actually do, the documentation is a bit oblique. Either experiment with it a bit or try to find some code that uses it and look how they do it...

Comment: ... or [read the code](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gdk-pixbuf/tree/gdk-pixbuf/gdk-pixbuf-animation.c).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After taking a look at the [GtkImage source code](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkimage.c), I am afraid there is no signal that is generated when the animation is completed. However, you should be able to restart the animation by calling `gtk_image_set_from_file()` or `gtk_image_set_from_animation()`.

To completely solve your initial issue, I propose you create a subclass of GtkImage. It should behave exactly like GtkImage, except that `animation_timeout` should send a signal if `delay < 0` around [line 1315](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gtk/gtkimage.c).

Information about creating a subclass of a GObject (note that GtkImage is a GObject) can be found [here](http://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/howto-gobject.html).

Comment: Thank you. So far my solution is to simply re-call gtk_image_set_from_file() which causes the animation to restart. However this is sub-optimal. I can't believe there is no way to restart an animation without resorting to such a drastic and  inefficient method.

Comment: I wish I could accept your answer and give you the 100 reputation because clearly you spent some time doing on the problem for me. Is there a way I can just give you some reputation since you did partially answer my questions?

Comment: Well, if the answer gets 2 upvotes and you do not accept it, I'd get 50 points after the bounty expires. Anyway, thank you for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

Based on user1202136's answer the following code snippets show the solution. I post this in case others find it useful.

The basic idea is to use `GdkPixbufAnimation`, `gdk_pixbuf_animation_new_from_file` and `gtk_image_set_from_animation`

The following code snippet(s) show how to do it.

```
GtkWidget *images[3][5];
GdkPixbufAnimation *animations[3][5];

/* Initial setup of animated gifs */
for( y = 0; y < 3; y++ )
{
    for( x = 0; x < 5; x++ )
    {
        /* set each Image widget to spin GIF */
        sprintf( filename,"%d-%d.gif", y+1,x+1 );
        images[y][x] = gtk_image_new();
        animations[y][x] = gdk_pixbuf_animation_new_from_file ( filename , &error);
        gtk_image_set_from_animation (GTK_IMAGE(images[y][x]), animations[y][x]);
        gtk_fixed_put(GTK_FIXED(frame), images[y][x], (x*120) + 20, (y*120) + 20);
    }
}


/*  now to restart the animations use the images and animations array already stored in memory,
    no need to re-read the animations from disk so this happens quickly
*/

/* restart animated gifs */
for( y = 0; y < 3; y++ )
{
    for( x = 0; x < 5; x++ )
    {
        gtk_image_set_from_animation(GTK_IMAGE(images[y][x]), animations[y][x]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is old but here goes my .02 cents as to help some intrepid voyager.

I do it in another way using the "iter" object and cairo for paint a drawing area with the animation, for my application works like charm.

```
GtkWidget *drawing_area;
GdkPixbufAnimationIter *iter;
GdkPixbufAnimation *pb;
GdkPixbuf *pixbuf;

gboolean on_drawing_area_draw( __attribute__((unused))GtkWidget *widget, cairo_t *cr, __attribute__((unused)) gpointer data)
{
gdk_cairo_set_source_pixbuf(cr, pixbuf, 0, 0); // tells cairo to use pixbuf as source

cairo_paint(cr); // fill the drawing area with the animation

return FALSE;
}

static gboolean mytimer(gpointer user_data) 
{
GTimeVal time;

g_get_current_time(&time);

gdk_pixbuf_animation_iter_advance(iter, &time); // advance/keep still based on time (= or >)

pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_animation_iter_get_pixbuf(iter); // get new pixbuf

gtk_widget_queue_draw(drawing_area);

g_timeout_add(gdk_pixbuf_animation_iter_get_delay_time(iter), mytimer, NULL);

return FALSE;
}


void init()
{
GTimeVal time;

pb = gdk_pixbuf_animation_new_from_file("image.gif", NULL); // load animation from file into pixbuf

g_get_current_time(&time);

iter = gdk_pixbuf_animation_get_iter (pb, &time); // get an iter object using time as reference

pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_animation_iter_get_pixbuf(iter); // get the first frmae

mytimer(NULL); // do again
}
```

Then you can stop the animation by passing the same *time parameter as the last frame* to "gdk_pixbuf_animation_iter_advance()" and you can restart from begining by freeing the *iter* object and asking for a new one. If you do nothing it will keep repeating the animation.

The only caveat is that you *must* use *libgdk_pixbuf 2.42.0 or above* because there is a bug that causes a memory leak when dealing with "iter" objects.